# crystal syntax basic selection formula

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I will skip how much I hate CR and how much it makes me lose my mind.

I have two columns, one is filled with dates and the other is filled with prices.  ALL I want to do is select the price that correlates with the latest date in the date column.  This MUST be done in crystal syntax.  ANY help is appreciated since any search relating to "selection formulas" for crystal 2008 in google or elsewhere turns up an incredible amount of information that does not pertain to my selection formula.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an easy way to ONLY select the maximum date, but I have a trick to just show the most recent date.

1. On the menu go to report > Section Expert
2. Left side select Details
3. right side press the X-2 for suppression
4. enter your date field not equal to the maximum date - ie: {table.date} <> MAXIMUM({table.date})

This will suppress all the other date and show the maximum.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This does work based on how I worded my question so I do thank you for you response.  However I need to be able to select the latest date within a group so I apologize for missing this key detail.  I have tried several different formulas but crystal syntax does not appear to accomodate something similar to a WHERE clause in SQL.  I believe my only issue is being able to specify the group with the formula you provided. {table.date} <> MAXIMUM({table.date}) 

Is it possible to specify a grouping within your formula?

Comment: Yup, you can do the same on the groups.  Just replace step 2 with  Group Header 1.  However scrap that solution, I found what you are looking for.

Comment: My response to your last suggestion was information that is IN ADDITION to my original statement.  I'm not only looking for the latest date, I'm looking for a price in a separate column which correlates with the latest date, within a group.

Comment: (more info)....My report reflects a column of dates, a column of prices and a 3rd column of products.  I am grouping by product and displaying all prices and dates for that specific product.  I need to separate and display the price which correlates to the latest date within the product grouping without suppressing everything else.

Nothing I have come across indicates that crystal is capable of doing this without some esoteric knowledge of crystal syntax itself.

I believe the first step in your second suggestion needs to be reevaluated, it sent me in the wrong direction.

Comment: Okay, how about this.  Follow the 2nd solution below but change step 4 to {table.date} = MAXIMUM({table.date}, {table.product})  This will return the latest date & price / product.

Comment: If I tell each group to select the latest dated record then this suppresses everything else within the group.  This piece of data needs to be separated WITHOUT suppressing all other records.  I appreciate your efforts ca_wan.  Unfortunately I don't have any other options unless we want to lose the client and I lose my job which is not an option.  I have convinced my bosses to find another program to crystal as it creates more problems than it solves.  In the mean time, I'm still pursuing an option with subreports which DRASTICALLY increases the run time and lowers company performance.

Comment: But I think we're so close.  My last ditch effort to be helpful is using a formula and an if statement.  If {table.date} = maximum({table.date},{table.product}) then {table.date}, then another for the price.  Place it in the Details with the other dates and it will be separate.  Sorry if it's not helpful.  It's the last idea I have without suppressing.

Comment: CA_WAN:  you saved me and I greatly appreciate it.  I made a slight modification to the formula but it works.  The part where you are specifying a group within the formula is what I was not completely aware of.  I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

To only select the latest date, use the Select Expert Grouping

1. On the menu go to report > Section Expert > Group...
2. Select the date field you want to use
3. Select Formula Editor...
4. enter your date field equal to the maximum date - ie: {table.date} = MAXIMUM({table.date})

This will only return the latest date.